# Display rich text in tool tip

Tags: html, ui

In this particular website, when you hover your mouse over a particular region, it displays something that is clickable. I know of tool tips, but in my experience, I have only used tool tips to show static text, not click able html text.
http://www.cry.org/projects/projects.html

What technology do you think is being used here? Also, is this a tool tip?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

These aren't tooltips like those created with a `title` attribute in HTML. This is normally called a "rich tooltip" and is done using an absolutely or relatively positioned HTML element with an appropriate z-index if required, so full HTML markup can be used. While it could be done [with CSS alone](http://sixrevisions.com/css/css-only-tooltips/) in modern browsers, Javascript is most often used to show and hide the element, sometimes with a fade effect.

Many Javascript UI libraries implement similar functionality, see e.g. [this JQuery UI demo](http://view.jqueryui.com/master/demos/tooltip/default.html), dijit.Tooltip, etc.

Comment: Thanks. But in the jquery example, as soon as I go over the tooltip, it vanishes.

Comment: I find that it doesn't if you click in the field first (so that it gains focus). That tooltip seems to be a work in progress, see http://wiki.jqueryui.com/w/page/12138112/Tooltip for discussion & documentation.